# How can I show the correct object from my viewmodel according to what row is tapped?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mobile, swiftui

I am stuck when the user tap a row , I am looking to show the correct sentences object to the question view.

Any help regarding the implementation would be great because I am kinda stuck.

Thank you :)

VIEWMODEL

```
class ViewModel {
     var sentences:[Model] = [           
            Model(sentence: [
                    Model.Word(syllabe:["tian","qi"]),
                    Model.Word(syllabe: ["hao"])]
                    , translation: "Sentence one "),
          
            Model(sentence: [
                        Model.Word(syllabe: ["wo"]),
                        Model.Word(syllabe: ["yao"]),
                        Model.Word(syllabe: ["chi","fan"])]
                      , translation: "Sentence two")
        ]

// Should I add a function here? 


}
```

VIEWS

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(vm.sentences) { sentence in                
            NavigationLink(
                destination: QuestionView(),
                label: {                
                    Text(sentence.translation) 
                  })
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
struct QuestionView: View {    
    let vm:ViewModel = ViewModel()  
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //How to show the correct detail image according to the row tappe? , should i add a function in my viewModel ?

            QuestionDetailImage(model: vm.sentences[0].sentence[0])           
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the selected object from the parent to the detail view in the `NavigationLink`

So in `ContentView` you change the loop

```
ForEach(vm.sentences) { sentence in                
    NavigationLink(
        destination: QuestionView(model: sentence),
        label: {                
            Text(sentence.translation) 
        })
}
```

and then change the `QuestionView` to use the Model object

```
struct QuestionView: View {    
    let model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            QuestionDetailImage(model.sentence /* not sure what you need here */)           
        }
    }
}
```